# Ms Access - Missing operator (LEFT JOIN)

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I have problem with `LEFT JOIN` query which is working in `SQL`, but when I try to query MDB database it doesn´t work.

Here it is:

```
Select PH.[ID], PH.[SText], PH.[Datum] ,PHpol.[SText], PHpol.[Mnozstvi], PHpol.[kcJedn], PHpol.[RelSzDPH], PHpol.[SDph], skst.[ID] 
from PH LEFT JOIN PHpol ON PH.[ID] = PHpol.[RefAg] 
LEFT JOIN Skz ON PHpol.[RefSKz] = Skz.[ID] 
LEFT JOIN Skst ON Skz.[RefStruct] = Skst.[ID] 
WHERE RelforUh = 2 
AND RelCr=43 
AND Datum BETWEEN #2015-01-01# AND #2015-09-01#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access, you need parentheses for multiple joins:

```
Select PH.[ID], PH.[SText], PH.[Datum] ,PHpol.[SText], PHpol.[Mnozstvi], PHpol.[kcJedn], PHpol.[RelSzDPH], PHpol.[SDph], skst.[ID]
from ((PH LEFT JOIN 
       PHpol
       ON PH.[ID] = PHpol.[RefAg] 
      ) LEFT JOIN
      Skz 
      ON PHpol.[RefSKz] = Skz.[ID]
     ) LEFT JOIN
     Skst
     ON Skz.[RefStruct] = Skst.[ID]
WHERE RelforUh = 2 AND RelCr=43 AND
      Datum BETWEEN #2015-01-01# AND #2015-09-01#
```

Answer (score 0):

In `MS-Access` you need to add `parentheses` if you have to query on more than *two tables*. Structure goes like this..

**Syntax for when you have two tables**

```
Select <column list> 
From Table1 Join Table2
on Table1.Col = Table2.col
where <your conditions>
```

**Syntax for more than two tables**.

```
Select <column list> 
From (Table1 Join Table2
on Table1.Col = Table2.col)
Join Table3 on Table2.col = Table3.col
where <your conditions>
```

`()` make sure that whatever is written inside it, act as a table. If you have more tables then you can join them in the same fashion. You can read more about joining multiple tables in MS-Access [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243855(v=office.12).aspx)

Well you can re-write your query as follows.

```
Select PH.[ID], PH.[SText], PH.[Datum] ,PHpol.[SText], PHpol.[Mnozstvi], PHpol.[kcJedn], PHpol.[RelSzDPH], PHpol.[SDph], skst.[ID] 
from ((PH LEFT JOIN PHpol ON PH.[ID] = PHpol.[RefAg])
LEFT JOIN Skz ON PHpol.[RefSKz] = Skz.[ID])
LEFT JOIN Skst ON Skz.[RefStruct] = Skst.[ID] 
WHERE RelforUh = 2 
AND RelCr=43 
AND Datum BETWEEN #2015-01-01# AND #2015-09-01#
```